# "Request new password" is not working!

Tags: emails, users

I have set the address of the server email address inside the Drupal Site Information, but it is not sending email to any users, when I start to request a new password for any users.

I feel I have missed something! maybe server email password!? how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: It started to work and I do not really know why email is too slow!

The problem at the moment is that, anytime I receive the email, the New password page link is expired.

Comment: That would be a server issue, not a drupal issue. Check with your server admin.

Comment: Please update your question to properly reflect the problem.